# Is there a way to get separate line characters in an array to output in the console panel on one line?

Tags: java

I wrote some code in Java, but am having trouble making the character output in Console panel all on one line...

Here's the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = ("Hello World!");
        List<Character> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<sample.length();i++) {
        
        colors.add(sample.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(colors);
        }
    }
}
```

The out put when I run the code is like this:

```
[H]
[H, e]
[H, e, l]
[H, e, l, l]
[H, e, l, l, o]
[H, e, l, l, o,  ]
[H, e, l, l, o,  , W]
[H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o]
[H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o, r]
[H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o, r, l]
[H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o, r, l, d]
[H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o, r, l, d, !]
```

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what exactly you want to happen? Currently, I can't tell what behavior you are after. So please [edit] your question to add your expected output.

Comment: if you want characters to be printed on same line, please use ``System.out.print()`` instead of ``System.out.println()``

Comment: Are you by any chance looking for `System.out.print(colors)`? (note: `colors` is an odd name for this array).

Comment: each character from each line to join together (to spell "Hello World!)

Comment: @user1924813, you can use one liner ```sample.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).forEach(System.out::println);```  which will each character in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colors is a an ArrayList, so when you're running `System.out.print(colors)`, it uses the default toString implementation of ArrayList, which is all elements with commas between them wrapped by[].

if you want to print it as a regular sentence, you can either print it element at a time (`colors.foreach(System.out::print)`) or concatenate it into a string and print it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = ("Hello World!");
        List<Character> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<sample.length();i++) {
        
        colors.add(sample.charAt(i);
        }

        System.out.println(colors);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!! Hours of agonising pain...I knew it was something like that...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an array of characters to be printed as separate characters, don't use `println(array)`.  Instead, either write a loop to print each character without anything added, or convert to a String.

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = ("Hello World!");
        for (int i=0; i<sample.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(sample.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The above in itself is not too useful, since you're not doing anything except taking the string apart and printing each character. But then again, I don't understand your intent.  Maybe you want to print strings of increasing length?

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = ("Hello World!");
        for (int i=2; i<=sample.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(sample.substring(0, i));
        }
    }
}
```

In this second example, `i` is the index of the first character not printed (i.e., one past the end), and since I assume you don't want a zero-length string printed, the counting starts at 2.